# HowTo use support.v7.preference with AppCompat and potential drawbacks

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-preferences, preferencescreen, preference-v7

I was trying to implement preferences for an AppCompat app, using support.v7.preference. It took me a couple of days to fiddle through it, since support.v7.preference has some significant differences to the native preferences... which isn't too bad once you know, but unfortunately there's little documentation out there. I thought I'd share my findings so others don't have to go through the same pain.

---

### So... question:

How do you best implement Preferences for AppCompat apps (with PreferenceFragment and AppCompatAcitivity being incompatible)?

### Here are a couple of related questions:

- [Preference sub-screen not opening when using support.v7.preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701740/preference-sub-screen-not-opening-when-using-support-v7-preference)
- [How to move back from Preferences subscreen to main screen in PreferenceFragmentCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494548/how-to-move-back-from-preferences-subscreen-to-main-screen-in-preferencefragment)
- [PreferenceFragmentCompat requires preferenceTheme to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070670/preferencefragmentcompat-requires-preferencetheme-to-be-set)
- [How do I create custom preferences using android.support.v7.preference library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621403/how-do-i-create-custom-preferences-using-android-support-v7-preference-library)

### Official docs here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Solution 1: Native `PreferenceFragment` with `AppCompatActivity`

In AndroidStudio, choose *File > New Project >...> SettingsActivity*. This template uses a workaround that retrofits the native `PreferenceFragment` to work with `AppCompatActivity`, similar to the `support.v4.Fragment` or the `support.v7.PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

- Pro: you can now use the native Preference functionality within an
  `AppCompat` app. It's a quick approach when using the AS template, and you can stick to the existing Preference docs and workflows.
- Con: the retrofitting isn't very intuitive or clean. Also since it's usually advisable to use support libs where available, I'm not sure how future-proof this approach is.

---

### Solution 2: `support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat` with `AppCompatActivity`

- Pro: maximizes compatibility
- Con: a lot of gaps to bridge. Also this might not work with any of the existing preference-extensions-libs out there (eg. `ColorPicker` or `FontPreferences`).

Should you choose not to use Solution 1 (I'm still not sure which of the two is more future proof), there are a couple of drawbacks when using `support.v7.preference`.

Important drawbacks of using Solution 2 are mentioned below.

**Dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

**Theme:**
You'll need to define a *`preferenceTheme`* in your styles.xml, otherwise running your app will raise an exception.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

You might wanna split this into different styles for 7+/14+/21+. A lot of people complain about this being buggy at the time of this writing. There is a very comprehensive answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108439/2699247).

**Behavior changes:** using the native preferences is extremely straight forward: all you need to do is define/maintain your `preferences.xml` and use `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)` within your `PreferenceFragment`. Custom preferences are easily done by sub-classing `DialogPreference`, and then just referenced to within the `preferences.xml`... bam, works.

Unfortunately, `support.v7.preference` has had everything related to dealing with `Fragment` stripped out, making it loose a lot of it's built-in functionality. Instead of just maintaining an XML, you now have to sub-class and override a lot of stuff, all of which is unfortunately undocumented.

**PreferenceScreens:** `PreferenceScreens` are no longer managed by the framework. Defining a `PreferenceScreen` in your `preference.xml` (as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Subscreens)) will display the entry, but clicking on it does nothing. It's now up to you to deal with displaying and navigating sub-screens. Boring.

There is one approach (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34944339/2699247)), adding a `PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartScreenCallback` to your `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. While this approach is quickly implemented, it simply swaps the content of the existing preference fragment. Downside is: there is no back navigation, you're always 'at the top', which isn't very intuitive for the user.

In another approach (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32713331/2699247)), you'll also have to manage the back stack in order to achieve back navigation as expected. This uses `preferenceScreen.getKey()` as a root for each newly created/displayed fragment.

When doing so, you might also stumble over the `PreferenceFragments` being transparent by default and adding up oddly on top of each other. People tend to override `PreferenceFragmentCompat.onViewCreated()` to add something like

```
// Set the default white background in the view so as to avoid transparency
view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.background_material_light));
```

**Custom DialogPreference:** Making your own preferences has also gone from trivial to boring. `DialogPreference` now has anything that deals with the actual dialog, removed. That bit now lives in `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`. So you'll have to sub-class both, then deal with creating the dialog and displaying it yourself (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32812614/2699247)).

Looking at the source of `PreferenceFragmentCompat.onDisplayPreferenceDialog()` shows that it knows how to deal with exactly 2 dialog preferences (`EditTextPreference`, `ListPreference`), everything else you'll have to implement yourself using `OnPreferenceDisplayDialogCallback`s... one wonders, why there is no functionality to handle sub-class of `DialogPreference`!

---

Here is some code that implements most of these workarounds and boxes them in a lib module:

https://github.com/mstummer/extended-preferences-compat.git

Main intentions were:

- Remove the need to extend and fiddle with `Activity` and `PreferenceFragment` in each app/projects. `preference.xml` is now again the only per-project file to change/maintain.
- Handle and display `PreferenceScreens` (sub-screens) as expected.
- Un-split `DialogPreference` to restore the native behavior.
- Handle and display any sub-class of `DialogPreference`.

Don't think it's clean enough to be just used out of the box, but it might give you some hints when dealing with similar issues. Give it a spin and let me know if you've got any suggestions.

Comment: You are a life-saver Max @maxdownunder!!

Comment: Does this work with sub-screens though? Seems to not be having any effect.

Comment: Got it. I had "addPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.settings )" instead of "I had "setPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.settings, rootKey )" inside "PrefrenceFragmentCompat::onCreatePreferences(..)"

Comment: I had no clue `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'` was even an option, thanks for pointing that out and saving me the headache!

Comment: So Google has effectively deprecated this whole feature. Who has time to mess about with all this? It's likely much quicker to roll your own UI and save to shared prefs.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution to this, that i'd love feedback on.

I made a custom layout for my preferencefragment, with a "Back" button in the upper left corner.

First, in the "onCreatePreference" i store away the root PreferenceScreen:

```
root = this.getPreferenceScreen();
```

Then, I add the OnPreferenceStartScreenCallback as described above and in other threads to make the fragment go to subscreen, but in my "onPreferenceStartScreen" i also set the back button to visible like this:

```
    public boolean onPreferenceStartScreen(PreferenceFragmentCompat preferenceFragmentCompat, PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
        preferenceFragmentCompat.setPreferenceScreen(preferenceScreen);
        backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
}
```

Finally, the backButton clickhandler:

```
    setPreferenceScreen(root);
    back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This seem to work fine for me. Obviously the back stack won't work, but i can live with that since there is a Back button.

Not perfect, but given the abysmal API i think i'm happy.

I would love to hear if someone thinks there are any problems with this approach.