# Why I can't enforce EditTextPreference to take just numbers?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, edittextpreference

**GOAL:** Use `EditTextPreference` to take a number input from an user.

**PROBLEM:** I'm using `support.v7.preference`  and, from what I've understood, this library bring problems to creates a custom `DialogPreference` ([HowTo use support.v7.preference with AppCompat and potential drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983932/howto-use-support-v7-preference-with-appcompat-and-potential-drawbacks)). Anyway I tried to create a `NumberPickerPreference` extending `DialogPreference` but I got `ClassCastException`.

Also I found another approach: programmatically set the input type of an `EditTextPreference` object like below:

```
    EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("pref_edit_text");
    if (pref != null) {
       pref.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    }
```

No way, I always get a `ClassCastException` .

Last approach I tried : modify the xml

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

or  `android:numeric="integer"`

No way again, on the `Dialog` I get the full keyboard, so the user can write everything.

Is there a way to properly enforce `EditTextReference` to take just number input?

Comment: it is reported of this being an issue, maybe this helps : https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned" 
android:inputType="phone"
```

**EDIT:**

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

**EDIT:**

There´s this lib that is supposed to make it work, if you´re willing to try:

https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix

Reading their github page you can find examples of custom inputs and their example code that looks similar to what you are doing now:

"The sample app shows an example of setting (via XML) and querying (programmatically) the input type of the EditTextPreference:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:key="edit_text_test" />

EditTextPreference etPref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("edit_text_test");
if (etPref != null) {
    int inputType = etPref.getEditText().getInputType();
    // do something with inputType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding `android: inputType = "numberPassword"` to your XML file
Then you can set your custom keyboard  programmatically in your java like this:

```
 yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

The next thing you could do is to create a custom class:

```
  private class YourNumericKeyboardMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return source;
    }
}
```

The last step is to implement it to your EditText in order to make it display only the numbers:

```
 yourEditText.setTransformationMethod(new YourNumericKeyboardMethod());
```

After all this steps you should get a keyboard that has only numbers from 0 to 9 on it

Comment: I think that doens't work because it's more or less the same thing I was trying to do. You are using setInputType which is a method of EditText class, but I have an EditTextPreference object and I CAN'T cast it to Preference, to use GetEditText() in order to use setInputType.

Comment: Oh, I see... You can access to the methods with something like this:

Comment: EditTextPreference my_preference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("pref_edit_text");
if (pref != null) {
    mypreference.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
}

Comment: That's the problem. With support.v7 library you can't do that. It raises ClassCastException (fact that I already reported in the question ).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set inputType as the number.

```
android:inputType="number"
```